# laravel calculate percentage between two sub queries

Tags: laravel, subquery

```
        $orders = Order::with(['orderItems' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('parent_id', null)->with([
                'orderItemAttributes', 'orderItemType', 'unitWorks.files', 'files',
                'child.unitWorks.files', 'child.orderItemAttributes',
                'child.orderItemType', 'child.files'
            ])->withCount([
                'unitWorks',
                'unitWorks as unitWorks_done_count' => function ($query) {

                    $query->whereNotNull('start')->whereNotNull('end');
                },
                'unitWorks as unitWorks_undone_count' => function ($query) {
                    $query->whereNull('end');
                },
            ]);
        }, 'customer', 'orderType'])->filter($request->input('customer'), $request->input('order_type'), $request->input('status'), $request->input('factor_number'), $request->input('code'))
            ->orderBy('vip', 'desc')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
            ->paginate(10);
```

I want to return the percentage of records done and not done in the method `withCount`, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `API Resource` :
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-resources

something like this:

```
'percentage' => $this->unitWorks_done_count/Order::count()
```